# Remove files and directories even if not empty, except some directories

Tags: bash, find, rm

I am trying to remove all contents of a directory with some exclusions. I'm currently using this:

```
find . -type f | grep -vZf ../../exclude.file | xargs rm -rf
```

The `exclude.file` contains:

```
*log*
world*
crash-reports
banned-ips*
```

I don't want to remove the `world`, `log` or `crash-reports` folders or any of their contents (the * is to cover backups, which are generated as `world.zip`).

The command above does this, but it does not remove non-empty directories. E.g. the `Config` directory is left, but I need it removed.

I've also experimented with similar to the following:

```
find -maxdepth 0 -not -name '*log*' -not -name 'crash-reports' -not -name 'world*' | xargs rm -rf
```

But I still get the same result.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-type f` will only find files, not directories. `-maxdepth 0` will only ever find the directory you're searching in (`.`). You'll have to find the files you actually want to pass to `rm`.

The standard way to do this is to exclude directories *and all their contents* like this (untested!):

```
find . -mindepth 1 \( -name '*log*' -o -name 'crash-reports' -o -name 'world*' \) -prune -o -print
```

Comment: Embarassing. Thanks! I should have spotted that. Removing type -f does what I want, but it pays no attention to `'*logs*'`, deleting the logs folder. Specifying it as 'logs' leaves it alone but there will be 'abc.log' and 'thisisalog.txt' which I wanted to cover with `*log*`. Any suggestions?

Comment: That is not going to work but would delete the whole directory tree from the search point (in combination with `rm -r`). It is kind of ridiculous that this is the accepted answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer as it lead me to my answer. Your answer 'not possible' was less helpful, although valued and appreciated. 
I managed to get the desired result with:
    find . | grep -v -i -e "world" -e "logs" -e "crash-reports" -e "banned-*" | xargs rm -rf

Comment: @AndrewWright You don't know how `grep` works. The `-e` values are regular expressions. `*` in a regex does not what you obviously expect. Next problem: `find .` gives `.` as first result. Your `grep` matches `.` and `rm -r .` deletes the whole directory tree.

Comment: All files I want to keep are in the directory the command is run from. I do want to delete the whole directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible IMHO with a single `find` run unless you know that all the directories to be skipped are in the first directory level.

**first step**

In the first run delete all the files (or rather: non-directories):

```
find . \( -type d \
  \( -name '*log*' -o -name 'world*' -o -name 'crash-reports' -o -name 'banned-ips*' \) \
  -prune \) -o \( -type d -o -print \)
```

**second step**

Create a dummy file in each (sub)directory to be skipped:

```
find . -type d \( \
  \( -name '*log*' -o -name 'world*' -o -name 'crash-reports' -o -name 'banned-ips*' \) \
  -o \( -path '*/*log*/*' -o  -path '*/world*/*' -o  -path '*/crash-reports/*' -o  -path '*/banned-ips*/*' \) \) \
  -exec touch {}/dontdeletethisdirecory
```

**third step**

Now all empty directories can be deleted. The simple approach is to pass all directories to `rmdir`. Only the empty ones get deleted:

```
find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

**optional last step**

You may now delete the dummy files:

```
find . -type -f -name dontdeletethisdirecory -delete
```